# query for records that do not exist

Tags: mysql, vb.net, null

```
SELECT today.status, GROUP_CONCAT(tomorrow.work_order order by line), today.code, today.events  
FROM today LEFT JOIN tomorrow 
   ON today.code = tomorrow.code   
   WHERE today.status like '1%' or  
      (today.status like '3%' and tomorrow.work_ordertext is null) 
      GROUP BY today.code
```

I am having issues with the 'tomorrow.work_ordertext is null' statement. tomorrow.code and tomorrow.work_ordertext may not even exist in the table, so I am guessing it shouldn't really be a null statement. I am looking for a way to pull rows from the today table if no records exists on the tomorrow table once the status is like 3 in the today table. Sorry if it sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT today.status, GROUP_CONCAT(tomorrow.work_order order by line), today.code, today.events  
  FROM today LEFT JOIN tomorrow   
ON today.code = tomorrow.code   
WHERE today.status = 1 or    
  (today.status = 3 and isnull( tomorrow.work_ordertext ))  
  GROUP BY today.code
```

I took out the like for the status as it will match 1, 10, 1b, 1somethingweird.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this didn't work. Or at least I am getting a time out error each time.

Comment: Can you a 'desc' on the query and post that?